# Rails - Render Request Referrer with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, request, render

Looking for a clean way to render the action and controller of the request referrer in case a validation fails for a resource controlled by another controller. This is because the resource can be created from multiple different views.

I have done along the lines of this so far:

```
        if @resource.save

            redirect_to resource_path(@resource)
        else
            request_referer_controller = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)[:controller]
            request_referer_action = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)[:action]
            search_param = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)[:search_param]
            render "#{request_referer_controller}/#{request_referer_action}", search_param: search_param if request_referer_controller.include? "search"
            render "#{request_referer_controller}/#{request_referer_action}" if request_referer_controller.include? "profile"
        end
```

But to me that's ugly somehow. There must be something built into rails to determine and render the previous request controller, action and any params right?

I'm getting used to Rails just having everything built in.

Comment: you can have redirect back. `redirect_to :back` Here is the good example of it : http://railscasts.com/episodes/131-going-back. Hope this helps..!!

Comment: problem with that is I lose my @resource errors. I think I'm approaching this all wrong...

Comment: may be, you can simple render the action directly, what you should do is create partial form and use that partial in different views. and in controller create action will render the respective action from which it comes. Here is some thought : http://pastie.org/8202709 ,  Also for better understanding create scaffold and see the code generate in controller. Hope this helps!!

Comment: yep. The cleanest way to do this is rendering the action directly.